# Propeller Force & Momentum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

An air stream is created by a propeller at velocity $\nu = 93.6\frac{m}{s}$

To calculate force applied by the propeller I used this formula:

$$F=\frac{1}{2}\rho\nu^2A$$

where:

- $\rho = 1.29 kg/m^3$ is the air density
- $\nu = 93.6\frac{m}{s}$ is the air velocity
- $A = 0.54m^2$ is the area swept by propeller's blades (This is for simplicity reasons)

Is this a correct way? I think it's correct because the answer results in $kg.m/s^2 = N$. By plugging the numbers I got a force of $F = 3051$ N

**How do I calculate momentum?**

I tried this:

$$p = m\cdot\nu$$

where $m$ is air mass. I calculated the mass this way:

$$m = \rho.A.\nu$$

Although this would give $kg/s$ because of velocity, but I'm working on 1 second, we simply eliminate the $s$ by multiplying by $t = 1$ sec, thus the mass is $m = 65.2kg$

$$p = 6102 \frac{kg.m}{s}$$

This is **twice** the force. Where did it go wrong?

Comment: Why can't the momentum be twice the force?

Comment: I'm assuming time passed is only 1 second only, by dividing the momentum by 1 I get twice the force, i.e 6102 insted of 3051

Comment: But they are fundamentally *different* concepts. Why do you assume they are the same?

Comment: I thought I could derive force from momentum, is this possible?

Comment: It is possible, but they are not identical quantities. Double check their units to see how they relate.

Comment: How to get force from momentum then? giving the momentum is 6102N.s

Comment: The force is related to the momentum via the [time derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_derivative): $F=dp/dt$. In the case you are considering, I'm not convinced that it makes sense to discuss the momentum of the propeller blade.

Comment: Note also that your equation for momentum is $\rho A\nu^2t$ is equivalent to $\rho A\nu^2$ for your arbitrary $t=1s$; this is your force equation multiplied by 2, hence the factor difference.